# M16 dimmable LED flickering with dimmable switch

Tags: led

I recently moved to home and decided to replace halogen MR16 with LED MR16. I bought DiCUNO MR16 LED Light Bulbs (*https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0B2525LNG?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details*) from Amazon, later I realized that I need to buy LED dimmer switch too. I bought Zigtiger LED Dimmer Switch (*https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08P5MDRDT?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details*) too. With old switch, LED bulbs were working, it just that I can't dim and sometimes it flickered. There was four halogen connected to a single switch and only two were working.
After I changed to an LED dimmer switch, only one LED(out of 4) worked and flickering too. What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to replace the driver transformer too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the drivers need to be dimmable too. All 3, the led, driver and dimmer have to be compatible.